# multiplication of 3 value extracted from mongodb in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have a document in mongodb as follow:

```
 "sentiment" : {
    "Value" : 0,
    "high" : 0
},
"quality" : {
    "Value" : 0,
    "high" : 0
},
"intensity" : {
    "Value" : 0,
    "low" : 0
}
```

Now I want to multiply quality.value*intensity.value*sentiment.value and then return the result here is my code:

```
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$Added");
    DBObject project = null;
        groupFields.put("value1", new BasicDBObject("$sum",
                "$sentiment.Value"));
        groupFields.put("value2", new BasicDBObject("$sum",
                "$quality.Value"));
        groupFields.put("value3", new BasicDBObject("$sum",
                "$intensity.Value"));
        groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
        DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
        stages.add(groupBy);
        DBObject valueMultiply = new BasicDBObject("$multiply", args);
        project = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
        project.put("value", valueMultiply );
        AggregationOutput output = collectionG.aggregate(stages);
```

Now my problem is this line:

```
DBObject valueMultiply = new BasicDBObject("$multiply", args);
```

I do not know how to do he multiplication of value1 and value2 and value3...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct your input to the [**`$multiply`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/#exp._S_multiply) operator as an array of `Objects` as in,

```
args = new Object[]{"$value1","$value2","$value3"};
```

and use it as:

```
DBObject valueMultiply = new BasicDBObject("$multiply", args);
```

The `$multiply` operator takes an array of [expressions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#field-path-and-system-variables), a valid expression *includes* a field path and remains valid until the field path resolves to a **numerical value**. In this case, the field paths, `$value1`, `$value2` and `$value3` resolve to numbers and hence are valid expressions.